# Magento 2 : Module Contribution

Tags: magento2

I am looking for the magento 2 extension contribution steps.

I have tried but it is not available any where,can somebody guide me on this.

Comment: Found that via Google http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/contributor-guide/contributing.html

Comment: Are you asking how to contribute to the Magento core, or how to write an extension, or how to submit an extension to the Marketplace, or what?

Comment: How to write new extension and submit to marketplace.magento.com